# Define automation testing

Tags: automated-testing

I have searched about automation testing and got idea what it is! but have not found any proper definition regarding AUTOMATION TESTING. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SQA. You wrote: "got idea what it is". Could you describe this idea? I have no idea what automation testing is, I only know what test automation is.

Comment: "Proper definitions" tend not to exist in SW world but depend on context. Did you mean (noun) Automation Testing or (transient verb) Automated Testing like the tag you used?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you meant "Automated Testing" rather than "Automation Testing". Here's the definition I use in my daily activities:

> **Automated Testing**
>
> Testing which is performed, to a greater or lesser extent, by a
>   computer, rather than manually.

It's part of a Glossary of Terms I have developed over the years that comes in handy when answering this sort of question. http://www.allthingsquality.com/p/testing-terms-glossary.html

I use a Glossary internally within my QA Team, and externally as well. It often helps when everyone on your team uses the same words for the same terms.